# php function implode tweaking

Tags: php, arrays, tweak

im trying to print an array using [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), but i want to tweak it, so the "glue" of the implode show every two element, and not in every element.

```
$nombreNombre=array('josh','13','mike','44','dude','98','scott','450');
echo '<li>' . implode('</li><li>', $nombreNombre).'</li>
```

with that im getting:

josh

13

mike

44

dude

98

scott

450

and i want:

josh 13

mike 44

dude 98

scott 450

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could run `$nombreNombre` through `array_chunk`, do an `array_map` to convert each pair to a string, then `implode`.

```
$arr = array('josh','13','mike','44','dude','98','scott','450');
$arr = array_chunk($arr, 2);
function repr($pair) { list($a, $b) = $pair; return "$a $b"; }
$arr = array_map("repr", $arr);
echo '<li>' . implode('</li><li>', $arr) . '</li>';
```

Comment: Can you give the sample code? I am wondering how you tackle it.

Comment: I like the way you used the built-in functions. Thanks